Did the events of Mtt 16:16-20 actually take place on different occasions?
We read in Matthew 16:16-20, of Peter's stellar response to Jesus query as to who the disciples say He is:

Simon Peter answered, “You are the Messiah, the Son of the living God.” 17 Jesus replied, “Blessed are you, Simon son of Jonah, for this was not revealed to you by flesh and blood, but by my Father in heaven. 18 And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it. 19 I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be loosed in heaven.” 20 Then he ordered his disciples not to tell anyone that he was the Messiah.

Now, Mark 8 also mentions the event of Peter's testimony, but it does not mention Jesus  appreciating Peter's response as in Verses 17-19 of Matthew . Mark  rather goes on to record  Jesus reprimanding Peter for the latter' advice against the ensuing Passion ( Verses 31-33).  Is it possible that the two events namely, testimony of Peter and Jesus promising him the keys of heaven   actually took place on two different occasions, on account of which Mark did not mention the second one ? What is the view of Bible scholars on such a possibility ?

Theoretically, yes, they might have been different; practically, it is almost certain that they were the same event.

Thanks, Dottard. If they were the same event, the question comes as to why Mark skipped the second one. Oversight ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan asks "why Mark skipped the second one" — None of the Gospels claims to be a complete history. Each was written from an individual perspective and for four different audiences. Mark is only 16 chapters long, as compared to Matthew's 28, so it would hardly be unexpected or significant that Mark omitted some details that Matthew decided to record.

Thanks Ray Butterworth. It is John  21:15-17 that narrates how the ' Keys of Heaven' were actually  given to Peter after the Lord's  Resurrection. Mtt 18:17-19 is but a precursor to that event. Matthew  may have felt it important to describe the precursor at an appropriate place. Interestingly, John does not have the precursor

Matthew 16:17-19 may have occurred on a different occasion. A crucial point is the mention of "Church", which is found only in Matthew 16:18 and Matthew 18:17. It is not mentioned in the other synoptic gospels or the Gospel of John.
The concept of the Church, derived from the Greek term ekklesia, refers to an assembly of believers in Jesus. They are a community united by their faith in Jesus Christ. Therefore, it might have been too early for this concept to be taught while Jesus was with His disciples. It could have been introduced before Jesus' ascension when He gave them the Great Commission in Matthew 28:19-20

19 Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, 20 and teaching them to obey everything I have commanded you. And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.” (NIV)

Matthew may have inserted 16:17-19 to illustrate that Peter's revelation of Jesus as the Messiah is a grace from God.
In Matthew 16:17, Jesus calls Simon "son of Jonah". The Hebrew name Yonah means 'dove', which is associated with peace, purity and the Holy Spirit. Therefore, Jesus indicated that Peter's revelation that He is the Messiah was embraced by the Holy Spirit.
The interpretation of the next two verses is controversial. Matthew's words may have complicated the situation, making it doubtful whether the disciples could grasp their meaning if Jesus mentioned them immediately after Peter's revelation. Jesus said His church would be built on 'this rock' (16:18). The term 'this rock' can only refer to the 'corner stone', which can only be Jesus Himself. Peter was given the keys of the kingdom of heaven (16:19), representing a delegation of authority to lead His church in the world. The authority to "bind or loose" (16:19b), is vested in the Church, not in Peter alone.
Therefore, I believe that Matthew 16:17-19 happened at a later time when Jesus entrusted His church to the disciples, with Peter as the leading figure. Matthew connected this event to the time when Peter was the first to reveal Jesus as the Messiah, through revelation by the Holy Spirit.

Only Matthew includes the story of Jesus giving the "keys' to Peter. So we cannot say for certain whether this happened at same time as Peter's testimony. Matthew certainly gives the impression that Peter's recognition of Jesus as the Messiah was the basis for his receiving the keys, for Jesus does this as a "reply" to Peter's declaration.
Scholars have long noted that Mark portrays the disciples in a more negative light than Matthew does. They consistently fail to understand him even when he performs miracles like walking on the water or feeding the 5,000.
Mark 6:51-53

51 He got into the boat with them and the wind died down. They were
astounded. 52 They had not understood the incident of the loaves. On
the contrary, their hearts were hardened.

When Matthew tells the story (ch 14) the negative comment about the disciples' faithlessness is omitted and they respond by affirming Jesus as the Son of God:

32 After they got into the boat, the wind died down.33 Those who were
in the boat did him homage, saying, “Truly, you are the Son of God.”

Lindsey Pherigo writes in the Interpreter's Bible:

Mark shared Paul's coolness and reserve toward (the apostles')
authority. He makes it plain to the reader that the 12 never understood
Jesus properly and therefore are not the best guides.

The question of Mark's attitude toward Peter is particularly vexed, because traditionally Mark is seen as Peter's follower or spiritual son. But some see in Mark's gospel a pro-Pauline critique of Peter's failure to understand. This question is discussed at length in the article Peter in Mark's Gospel by E. Best.
Conclusion: If Matthew's gospel is generally more pro-Peter than Mark's (which is more pro-Paul) then it stands to reason that Matthew would include Peter's reception of the keys while Mark would not. It is hard to know whether Mark omitted the story of the keys or Matthew simply had more information. But in Matthew's account, one follows immediately upon the other rather, rather than the two events happening at different times.

Thanks Dan Fefferman, for the scholarly inputs. Will you please edit the first line and replace 'Matthew' with 'Jesus '?

thanks for the correction. The older I get the more these things happen.

That is exactly what God gives us grandchildren for ! They are better off with  Apps and AI.

Dan Fefferman, please let the readers know what your personal assessment of the writeup of E.Best are . One can understand why John the Evangelist takes a dig at Judas Iscariot . How come Mark allowed his Gospel narrative to be influenced by personal opinion and other Apostles school of thought , when it describes Peter.
